# Как вывести число в 16-ричной системе счисления заглавными буквами?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Здравствуйте! Я делаю стандартный вывод числа в 10СС в число 16СС. Проблема в том, что мне необходимо вывести число заглавными буквами, например, "EDA", а не "eda".
Так вот, есть ли какой-нибудь способ так сделать стандартными методами, не прибегая к алгоритму перевода числа?
Если что, вот код:

```
int n;
cin >> n;
cout << hex << n;
```

Comment: Я даже знаю откуда, скорее всего, эта задача.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте `<< uppercase <<`:

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << hex << uppercase << n;
}
```